# How to make WordPress pages where only certain (multiple) areas of content are editable

Tags: php, wordpress

It has been a few years since I properly worked with WordPress. Now I have a proposal to build a WordPress site where every page has a custom design and only some areas of each page is editable.

The reason for this is to build a bespoke layout on each page which cannot be messed up by someone non-technical editing it in the CMS, except for small areas which they can customise.

e.g. A page contains one div which has some text in it, which can be edited in the WP admin backend, but the rest of the page cannot be edited.

Can this be done? How?

**Edit: There needs to be multiple editable areas not just one.** I know how to make custom pages/templates.

Comment: Based on your edit, maybe WordPress isn't the best tool for this job?

Comment: You might be able to create custom pages that display only specific pre-created posts, and let the users edit those posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a plugin called [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) which does exactly what I required.

Answer (score 0):

One method may be to create new page templates. Just create a new file in your main theme folder (or the templates folder if there is one). As long at the top of that file contains the line:

```
/* 
     Template Name: <your template name>
*/
```

You can design the page however you want. The data pulled from the admin section will go wherever you invoke

```
the_content();
```

The rest of the page can be hardcoded.

Then on the post edit page, on the right side (usually), you can choose the template with your template name for that page. It may be a good idea to copy the current post.php or single.php into your custom file and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

For restricting access you can look at setting up user levels and keep your content contributors as "Authors" instead of "admins" so they can't change themes or edit settings.

(See https://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels)

For creating specific unique pages with an area that gets changed you should look into custom Page Templates.  You can create a page template by dropping a php file with the right naming structure into your theme hierarchy and it will get picked up by the back-end as template option when you create a page.

(See https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)